# how to dynamically add columns in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

suppose, I have a flat file as a source in SSIS which contains 3 columns and its keep on changing

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
2   3   4
```

now I need that if the flat file is changed (suppose two new columns are added) then the destination file (table in SQL) should also be changed .

Comment: SSIS doesn't work that way. If the schema of your source data is changing, SSIS is not the correct tool for the job

Comment: I have an example of an SSIS package that generates a dynamic package. Maybe it can help you. But be aware that you need some C# skills also to change it. The example can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037650/Export-output-of-SQL-Server-script-to-Excel-SSIS).